# AttributeError: 'Directores' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentando obter um valor de uma classe bem simples, porém estou com  um problema que não consigo resolver. Segue os códigos abaixo:

**Classe principal:**

```
from directores.directores import Directores
# A classe Directores encontra-se em directores/directores.py

def main():
    print (Strings.start_description)

    # Sobrescrever arquivos encontrados
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Criando todos os diretรณrios
    directores = Directores(Parameters.main_folder + r"\\")
    print(directores.getInput_folder_SRTM())
```

**A classe Directores:**

```
class Directores(object):

    def __init__(self, main_folder):
        # Diretórios secundários de entrada - INPUT
        self.input_folder = main_folder + r"\Input\\"
        self.input_folder_SRTM = self.input_folder + r"SRTMs\\"

    def getInput_folder_SRTM(self):
        return self.input_folder_SRTM
```

**Com o seguinte erro:**

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 50, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in main
AttributeError: 'Directores' object has no attribute 'getInput_folder_SRTM'
```

Em cada pasta criei um arquivo vazio `__init__.py`

Se precisar de mais alguma informações estarei a disposição. E se me derem algumas dicas também agradeço muito!

Comment: Não temos como testar seu código, pois há dependências que não estão explícitas na pergunta, tal como `String`, `arcpy` e `Parameters`, porém, num teste básico, removendo essas dependências, seu código não reproduziu o erro citado: https://repl.it/@acwoss/SweetAdorableInterface. Poderia, então, [edit] e criar um [mcve] que demonstre o erro?

Answer (score 1):

A chance aí é que você tenha outra versão desse projeto, com outra pasta `directores` que contenha uma versão antiga do código, e ao fazer o `import` você esteja trazendo o arquivo dessa outra pasta.

Tente colocar essas linhas no início do seu arquivo que você chama de "classe principal":

```
from directores import directores as directores_module
print (directores_module.__file__)
```

Isso vai imprimir o caminho do arquivo `directores.py` que ele está importando.

Agora, o problema pode nem ser esse, mas vamos aproveitar para as demais dicas que você pediu:

1. Use Python 3. Não faz sentido começar um projeto com Python 2.7 hoje - é uma versão da linguagem com 10 anos de idade, e que sai de uso em um ano e 2 meses. Você perde *várias* melhorias - principalmente no tocante a tratamento de texto acentuado. Mesmo que você precise de Python 2.7 para outros fins no mesmo computador, o uso de `virtualenv` permite que você tenha projetos de Python 2 e Python 3 em paralelo na mesma máquina sem nenhuma ambiguidade
2. Use seus nomes com consistência. O guia de estilos de Python recomenda que se use nomes "snake_case": isso é, palavras em nomes de funções e variáveis são separadas com "_" - e apenas nomes de classe em "CamelCase". Você não é obrigado a seguir as convenções de estilo - mas misturar underscore com camel case *dentro* dos mesmos nomes (sério, dói os olhos só de olhar)
3. Se você está usando strings prefixadas com "r", não precisa dobrar as `\\` para separar diretórios - uma única `\` é o suficiente. Mas melhor ainda, em Python você pode usar a barra pra frente para separar diretórios - `/` mesmo no Windows. É uma forma mais universal e seu código não fica dependente de sistema. Melhor ainda: use Python 3.7 (vide dica 1) e use a pathlib em vez de strings para caminhos de diretórios. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html
4. Não use "getters" e "setters" se você não vai fazer nada com o valor dentro desses métodos. Em Python todos os atributos são públicos, exceto por convenção. Se tudo que seu método `getInput_folder_SRTM` vai fazer é devolver `self.Input_folder_SRTM`, não tem por que chamar o método - acesse o atributo direto na instância com `directores.Input_folder_SRTM` no seu outro módulo. Se você quiser transformar/filtrar o valor quando ele for setado, ou transforma-lo quando for usado, use [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) para escrever o getter e o setter - mas perceba que legal: você pode se preocupar com o property só numa outra faze do seu projeto e acrescentar getters e setters sem mudar nada do código que use o atributo.
5. Use um gerenciador de versões de código, como o [git](https://git-scm.com/) e ambientes isolados, como o [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). Pode ser que seu problema não seja o que  mencionei acima - mas está com bastante cara de ser devido a versões antigas do projeto espalhados pelo computador. Com git acaba esse problema de ter várias versões do mesmo código em pastas diferentes, conforme você vai aprendendo a usa-lo. E com o virtualenv você isola exatamente quais pacotes e módulos estão instalados para cada projeto de Python - evitando interferências entre versões diferentes.